# How do I add numbers to each subset in Wolfram mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-optimization, discrete-mathematics, mathematical-expressions, mathematica-8

Say I have a deck of 52 cards. I now remove two cards from the deck, say it is Diamond 2 and 4. I now create a subset {5} meaning I print every 5 card combination of the 50 cards I have left.

How do I now add back both the diamond 2 and 4 into each subset i.e. each set of 5 card combinations?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Is this even related to programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** Use resource function [`PlayingCardGraphic`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlayingCardGraphic/) to generate graphic

Converting to the right format is a bit messy, would have been easier if the ranks were generated in a different way.

```
newHands = 
 Subsets[deckPart, {5}] // Map[Join[#, cardsToRemove] & /* RandomSample];

hand = newHands // RandomChoice

(hand // 
    Map[StringSplit[#, 
       x : DigitCharacter .. | {"J", "Q", "K", "A"} :> x] &]) /. {v_, 
    s_} :> {If[MemberQ[{"J", "Q", "K", "A"}, v], v, ToExpression@v], 
    s} // 
 ResourceFunction["PlayingCardGraphic"][#, "CardSpreadAngle" -> .8] &
```

[image]

---

The number of 5 card subsets is

```
50!/(5! 45! = 2118760
```

it takes ~2.8s to compute and ~10s to display in the notebook on my machine.

```
suits = ToString /@ {\[SpadeSuit], \[HeartSuit], \[DiamondSuit], \[ClubSuit]}
ranks = CharacterRange["2", "9"]~Join~{"10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"}

deck = Outer[StringJoin, ranks, suits] // Flatten // RandomSample

cardsToRemove = {"2\[DiamondSuit]", "4\[DiamondSuit]"}

deckPart = deck // DeleteCases[Alternatives @@ cardsToRemove]

Subsets[deckPart, {5}] // Map[Join[#, cardsToRemove] & /* RandomSample]
```